# Touch ID and password at the same time?

Tags: iphone, password, touch-id

Is it possible to require both Touch ID and a password in order to unlock an iPhone?

Answer (score 2):

It's not only possible – it's mandatory!

Apple knew that they can't trust their fingerprint sensor to work 100% of the time, so they won't even allow you to enable Touch ID unless you also set a passcode. Once you've set them up, they're both equally capable of unlocking your phone. You can either "slide to unlock" and enter your passcode or just scan your fingerprint - whatever you prefer!

Edit for your clarification: Sorry for the misunderstanding! No, there's no way (Apple-approved; I'm not sure what jailbroken solutions exist) to have both layers of security at once. Either one can unlock your phone, but there's no way to require both. Like I said, Apple wants to always have a workaround for when the admittedly-fallible Touch ID reads a false negative. They'd never allow Touch ID to be an absolutely necessary component of the only way into your phone.

Comment: I mean, having to do both to unlock the phone, every time.

Comment: @ŠimeVidas Edited.

Comment: After a restart, the passcode is required to unlock the phone, the fingerprint reader is useless.  The fingerprint data stored on the phone is encrypted and can't be accessed until the phone is unlocked after each restart.  Unless apple changes this design, which is doubtful since it would be a less secure solution, there would be no way to require both.    There appears to be some 2 factor authentication apps in the app store that might provide what your looking for, I didn't study them for long but at least once appeared to be there to increase security.